# How to mock a method call which is being called using setattr during class instantiation?

Tags: python-2.7, mocking

I have the following class:

```
class ClassA(Object):
    VERSIONS = {
        '1': {
            'x': a.b.x.X # where x is the module and X is the class
        }
    }    
    ATTRS = ['y', 'z']
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        ...
        do_something... 
        ...
        for attr in ATTRS:
            setattr(self, attr, VERSIONS[ver][attr]())
```

I am using the above code as follows:

```
class_a = ClassA()
class_a.x.y
```

where x is a module and y is the method in that module

I need to mock this call now. How do I mock it, since the method y is not part of ClassA?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done as follows:

```
mock_class_a.return_value.x.y = value_to_return
```